# JS: Как в array добавить елементи взяв иx из object?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть object, нужено запушить его values в [], если key === 'name'.

Вот пример моего кода, который не работает.

```
const projects = responseJSON.response.projects;
const allNames = [];

for (let key in projects) {
     Object.keys(projects).find(key => {
        if (key === 'name') {
           allNames.push(value)
        }
     });
}
```

Или так :

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(projects)) {
      if (key === 'name') {
        allNames.push(value);
      }
}
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо!

Comment: Приведите пример данных для `projects`.

Comment: второй вариант работает

Comment: А чем не устроил `const allNames = projects.name ? [ projects.name ] : [ ];` ?)

Comment: А зачем вы скрываете область видимости для `key`? У вас в цикле `key` и в стрелочной функции -- `key` как название аргумента.

Answer (score 2):

Вы усложняете. Объект на то и существует, чтобы обращаться по ключу. Используйте
projects['name'] или projects.name

Но не помешает добавить проверку:

```
const key = 'name';
if(projects[key]){
    allNames.push(projects[key]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, хороший вариант. Подожду новых ответов перед тем как принимать ваш варинт.

Comment: Так лучше не писать, т.к. если `projects['name'] = false` или `projects['name'] = 0`, то код не отработает. Лучше заменить условие на `typeof projects['name'] != 'undefined'`. Итого можно написать решение в одну строку: `(typeof projects['name'] != 'undefined') && allNames.push(projects['name']);`

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, если нужен false или 0, это отдельный случай. Ваш вариант также не идеален - не исключает попадания в массив null. Весь код можно в одну строку запихнуть, только читать это потом как?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const projects = {
  a: {name: 'a'},
  b: {name: 'b'}
}
const values = Object.keys(projects).reduce((res, projectKey) => 
  projectKey === 'a' ? [...res, projects[projectKey]] : res, 
[]);

console.log(values);
```

```js
const projects = {
  a: {
    name: 'a'
  },
  b: {
    name: 'b'
  }
}
const allNames = [];



for (let key in projects) {
  if (key === 'a') {
    allNames.push(projects[key])
  }
}
console.log(allNames)
```

Comment: Всё было бы классно, если бы весь написанный код не сокращался до `projects.a`

Comment: Кстати да))) Про уникальность ключей-то я не подумал)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую такой вариант тоже!

Answer (score 0):

```
(typeof projects['name'] != 'undefined') && allNames.push(projects['name']);
```

Данный код подходит для случаев, когда `projects['name'] == 0` или `projects['name'] == false` или `projects['name'] == null`

Comment: в таком случае лучше сделать (projects && projects['name'])  чем писать typeof

Comment: @Qui-GonJinn нет, и я написал в ответе, почему стоит проверять на undefined. Проверка сущуствования переменной `project` вне рамках вопроса, т.к. автор её не проверяет.

Comment: Тогда уж использовать hasOwnProperty. {name: undefined} - ключ "name" есть? Есть